# Detect server status throughout the application android

Tags: android, android-internet

I am developing an application which requires internet access all the time. I am able to find if its connected to internet or not using the following code.

```
private Boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
    = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

However, there might be cases where, in the middle of the run, the server may go down, or there might be loss of internet. Could anyone plz tell how to handle this situation?? As of now, the app crashes if internet is lost. I want continuously monitoring of the internet connectivity.

Comment: "I am developing an application which requires internet access all the time" - that's a poor assumption for any mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

You can ping to Server and get the response code. If response code is `200` or `HttpStatus.SC_OK` then your Server is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

u can use `BroadcastReceiver` for your application to get notified whenever the connectivity changes . Have a look at docs: [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
and [Connectivity Monitoring](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) for detailed description.

I hope it will be helpful !